# how too delete junk folder in outlook email

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

OK so 50% of all my important emails end up in the junk folder clearly this is a 100% failure of a filter and i want all email to go to main inbox and not identify any email as junk. possible?

Answer (score 3):

The Junk Mail folder is built into Outlook.

If you do not wish to use it, then you can use the Junk Mail options (Outlook, Main Ribbon) to turn the filter OFF.

Please see below and below that, the Main Ribbon to get to the Junk Mail options.

[image]

[image]

Comment: i dont know what outlook your using but i dont have those options

Comment: The Outlook Junk options are available from the main ribbon (look at the icon pull downs at the left of the ribbon). Junk Mail options exist in Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016 (365). I think in Outlook 2007 before that. I will edit my post in a few minutes to clarify.

Comment: I added a clarifying screen shot for you and hope this will assist you.

Comment: ok, i figured it out. thanks for the help! couldn't have done it without you <3

Comment: You are very welcome and good luck with all the above.

Comment: You may wish to click on the "Answered" icon in your question. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to what John mentioned above, it is also suggested to add those important senders to your safe sender list via Outlook > Home > Delete > Junk > Junk Email Options > Safe Senders to make sure that Outlook will not identify emails from those important senders as junk.